# How to return X results in PHP where variable is true

Tags: php, html

I'm having a hell of a time figuring this out.

I'm able to pull data from a database no problem and show all of the results, however, I want to limit the number of results returned, I also want to only show results that have a status of 1 and ignore all with 0.

Here's what I have so far...

```html
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $dbtable . " ORDER by `id` DESC;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
?>
...other stuff...
            <?php
              while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
                $username = $row["username"];
                $user_photo = $row["user_photo"];
                $location = $row["location"];
                $status = $row["status"];
            ?>
            <li><img src="<?= $user_photo ?>" class="collab" data-username="<?= $username ?>" data-location="<?= $location ?>" /></li>
            <?php } ?>
```

Basically, I'd like to return the first 30 results that have a STATUS of 1. Is that possible? I don't have the foggiest idea how to approach that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your SELECT isn't in your question so it's hard to say what you should or should not be doing. Usually, a `WHERE` clause. I.e.: :`WHERE col='x'`

Comment: This should be done in the query, not the PHP side. Can you share the query you currently have?

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $dbtable . " ORDER by `id` DESC;";

Comment: `WHERE status = 1 LIMIT 30` you can remove the LIMIT if you want. Try that out. Should do what you want it to do. possibly a GROUP BY also.

Comment: I'll make it an answer then. Someone posted one, but I believe my comment helped you first.

Comment: You're welcome Robb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `WHERE` clause.

```
... WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 30
```

For more information, visit the following on MySQL.com:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

From the manual:

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Comment: Quick additional question; if I wanted to skip the first X results, is that easy?

Comment: @robbclarke sorry, I wasn't at my PC... that's exactly it.

Answer (score 2):

Both filtering rows and limiting the results can be done via the query. A `where` clause will allow you to filter the rows and a `limit` clause will, unsurprisingly, allow you to limit the returned results:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     $dbtable
WHERE    status = 1
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT    30
```

Comment: yeah, I did say that, unless you're not looking at comments

Comment: I caught your answer. Thanks, @Fred-ii-